# How to loop twice over the same vector?

Tags: loops, vector, foreach, rust

I am trying to update elements of a vector knowing where each other is, *i.e.* test all pairs of elements (unordered), while changing them. So I started naively writing this:

```rust
for x in &mut v {
    for y in &mut v {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But I cannot mutably borrow the vector twice, plus, I could simply avoid a lot of iterations, writing this:

```rust
for x in 0..v.len() - 1 {
    for y in x..v.len() - 1 {
        let mut xc = &mut v[x];
        let yc = &v[y];
        // ...
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, because I borrow an immutable and a mutable reference! How can I write this basic kind of loop? (I do need the mutability for at least one of the elements.)

Comment: A simple and straightforward option is for the code in `// ...` to work with indices `x` and `y`, i.e. refrain from creating long-lived references to individual vector elements in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of ownership will not let you borrow the same data mutably and immutably, so in safe Rust there is no possible solution to get the data at a certain index as an mutable and immutable reference.

This is probably not what you need anyway. Rust contains a feature that allows you to access multiple indexes in a slice:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let len = v.len();
    for x in 0..len - 1 {
        let (first, second) = v.split_at_mut(x + 1);
        let xc = &mut first[x];
        *xc = *xc + 1; //some code that uses xc and yc if y == x
        for yc in second {
            *xc = *yc + 1; //some code that uses xc and yc if y > x
        }
    }
}
```

`*xc = *yc + 1` is some example code that uses the references `xc` and `yc`. Note that the case where `x == y` must be handled separately.

Comment: `partition_at_index` reorders the slice. You want something like `let (xc, rem) = v[x..].split_first_mut().unwrap()`

Comment: Apologies, I did not read the documentation carefully. Should I update the answer or just delete it?

Comment: Oh, update it, definitely.